# Running db:migrate causes some 'validations' on production, can that be turned off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm pushing a working app (developed it locally) to a Heroku environment. When trying to run db:migrate on the production environment, the migrations fail because the postgreSQL seems to be doing some sanity checks that my sqlite on localhost wasn't doing, for instance:

- I created a migration for a post model and already defined a relationship to a (at that point) non existing comment model. Postgre is complaining that the table comment does not exist. (solved this by rearranging the migrations, bad I know)
- I use a sort of STI trick in my model in that the models Exercise, Video & Lesson all store their data in the same table (steps). Exercise has many Questions but when trying to create the table, Postgre is complaining about a missing table exercises.

Is there a way to fix the second error or is there a general way to prevent rails from the sanity checks (does the related table exist)?

EDIT:

Ok, so the relevant migration is this one:

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :exercise, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that there's no table `exercises`, because that one is named `steps`. So the referential integrity is breached for PostgreSQL resulting in the following error:

```
== 20151208132820 CreateQuestions: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:questions)
   (14.1ms)  CREATE TABLE "questions" ("id" serial primary key, "title" character varying, "exercise_id" integer, "content" text, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
   (5.2ms)  CREATE  INDEX  "index_questions_on_exercise_id" ON "questions"  ("exercise_id")
   (9.3ms)  ALTER TABLE "questions" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_5ba13b3a6e"
FOREIGN KEY ("exercise_id")
  REFERENCES "exercises" ("id")

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "exercises" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "questions" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_5ba13b3a6e"
FOREIGN KEY ("exercise_id")
  REFERENCES "exercises" ("id")
```

Comment: Did you try restart Heroku after deploy?

Comment: Ehh no not really... is that necessary? How do I do that?

Comment: Paste your migration and models related to the issue.

Comment: pasted the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think that the problem is coming from the `foreign_key` constraint, you can just remove it and check again.

A better solution is to mimic the production environment locally and make it work before pushing up.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key constraint isn't needed. I would always recommend using the same database on your localhost as you will on your production server.

Remove the foreign key, deploy and the migration will work :)